# Добавление классов к поcтам по slug - body_class()

Tags: wordpress

При создании кастомной темы WP пробую вывести в тег body дополнительные классы, если пользователь переходит на страницу бонусов или новостей (`example.com/bonuses/` `example.com/news/`), (классы `page_bonuses` и `page_news`, соответственно), но почему-то ничего не происходит.

```
function my_body_class_filter($classes)
{
if( is_single('bonuses') ){

    $classes[] = 'page_bonuses';
}elseif (is_single('news') ){
    $classes[] = 'page_news';
}
return $classes;
};

<body class="body" <?php body_class(add_filter('body_class', 'my_body_class_filter')); >
```

Что не так я прописываю в условных тегах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вызов неправильно построен.

В `functions.php` должно быть

```
function my_body_class_filter( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_name;
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_filter' );
```

В `header.php`

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

P.S. `is_single('slug')` не работает для страниц. Поэтому в моём коде к классам добавляется имя поста (slug). Это работает для любого типа поста, в том числе и для страниц.

Comment: Сделал как написано, изменений пока нету. Так и выводит в body class=" body customize-support"

Comment: Я не обратил внимания, что у вас страницы, а не записи. Скорректировал ответ.

Comment: Эмм, теперь конечно высыпало всё http://prntscr.com/jtn3pf Но мне так много не надо, и оно почему-то съело класс .body у тега body. Мне бы только к двум страницам выводить эти доп классы

Comment: Во-первых, вам это всё надо. На этом базируются многие плагины. А класс body вам как раз не нужен, если только вы его сами не используете в верстке, что странно. Но если сильно надо, то добавьте одну строку в фильтр перед return: `$classes[] = 'body';`

Comment: На самом деле мне не нужно такое полотно из классов http://prntscr.com/jtyv6l К тому же я не знаю как производить необходимую мне модификацию css если URL страници будет к примеру example.com/news/razvedenie-homyakov (Напомню что в этом случае мне всё ещё надо к body добавлять класс page_news) я просто не смогу привязаться к нужному классу

Comment: Вам это полотно чем мешает? На создание его уходит доли миллисекунд. Полотно нужно для разных плагинов и самого WordPress (logged-in admin-bar). мой код автоматически добавляет слаг страницы в классы - ровно то, что вы просили. На странице `/bonuses` будет добавлен класс `bonuses`, на странице `/news/` - класс `news`, на странице `razvedenie-homyakov` - класс `razvedenie-homyakov`.